# URL-NFC tag unique and identifyable request

Tags: nfc

I have the following problem: I'm developing a web-app which controls a lighting console and only on person at a time can control it. When somebody new visits the web-app this person gets control and this is the expected behavior. But I don't want anybody from anywhere else with the web-app url to take over control, just people standing in front of the lighting console.

My first approach was to use an tablet which creates a qr-code with a one-time-valid url. You take over control over the console when you scan the qr-code and follow the one-time-valid url and the tablet gets notified to regenerate the qr-code.

But may be there is a solution without an expensive tablet: is there a chance I can configure an NFC Tag so that this tag generates a new url on every tap, which cannot be reproduced? (eg by signing it with a private key)

It also has to support Android and iOS

Comment: it is not the job of nfc tag to generate new link, it is the job of the device who read the tag to generate an uniqe link and the overwrite the link in the tag. 
The secinario could be :
- you read the link from tag and save it .
- generate new link 
- re write the link on tag 
- end session

Answer (score 1):

Most standard NFC tags just read and write to some EPROM data chips, so the data is static on the card, while most cards have a unique serial number this is still static data.

There are some advanced cards out their that can run custom programs (one is called JavaCards https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Card ), so you could write a program that generates a unique URL you want and then present it to the card reader device as a standard NDEF message that would launch the devices browser to this dynamic URL.